# an error received while executing my function?

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions

When I execute the following:

```
function [ x ] = addya( varargin )
x=varargin{1};
t=varargin{1};
if(nargin>1)

for i=2:nargin
    t=t+varargin(i);
    end;
end
x=t;
```

The error i am getting is:

> addya(1,1) ??? Undefined function or method
>   'addya' for input arguments of type 'double'.

please suggest changes and errors.

Comment: Which input did you provide the functon with? You should change  `t=t+varargin(i);` with `t=t+varargin{i};` . After this change, I run the function as `x=addya(1,1,2,23,4)` and did not get any error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this function is saved in a file called `addya.m`.

Moreover, as mentioned by [il_raffa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870179/an-error-received-while-executing-my-function/30875274#comment49783847_30870179) there's a typo - inside the loop: you should access `varargin` using `{}`.

The following code works for me when saved as `addya.m`:

```
function [ x ] = addya( varargin )
    x=varargin{1}; %// Why is this needed?
    t=varargin{1};
    if(nargin>1)
        for i=2:nargin
            t=t+varargin{i};
        end;
    end
    x=t;
```

Also, I would suggest to refrain from using `i` as a loop index due to possible complication with complex numbers.

Comment: one more question when do you get this error,in the editor 'assigned variable 'x' might not be used'

Comment: thank you guys for the help and if please let me know the answer of the above question